# C++ fork() -- creating a "list" of processes

Tags: c++, fork

I have a program that creates new processes "one by one". Is it possible to change this code so it creates a "list" of processes – i.e. child 1 being the parent of child 2, child 2 being the parent of child 3, etc.?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "err.h"

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 pid_t pid;
 int i;

 cout << "My process id = " << getpid() << endl;

 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  switch ( pid = fork() ) {
  case -1:
    syserr("Error in fork");

  case 0:
    cout << "Child process: My process id = " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << "Child process: Value returned by fork() = " << pid << endl;
    return 0;

  default:
    cout << "Parent process. My process id = " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << "Parent process. Value returned by fork() = " << pid << endl;

   if (wait(NULL) == -1) 
   syserr("Error in wait");

 }  
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: this wont create 4 processes,it creates 2^4 processes

Comment: If child 1 is to be the parent of child 2, then the original process will not know anything about child 2 unless either child 1 or child 2 tells it; the problem is more severe for child 3 and then child 4.  Although child 4 could know about all its ancestors, its ancestors won't know anything about their most distant progeny.

Comment: Why would you want to create the process hierarchy in a linear, most-distant fashion?  Instead, it is probably more useful for a single parent to be directly related to all its children.  That way the parent can have a single array holding all its children's PIDs, for example.  In your desired scenario, each process knows only one parent and one child.  Extra work needs to be done to either communicate what they know, or to examine the process hierarchy to discover the full relationships.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the loop in order to dynamically set the depth of the *fork* tree,

```
// Set DEPTH to desired value

#define DEPTH 4

int main ()
{
  pid_t pid;
  int i;

  cout << "My process id = " << getpid() << endl;

  for (i=1 ; i <= DEPTH ; i++) {

    pid = fork();    // Fork

    if ( pid ) {
       break;        // Don't give the parent a chance to fork again
    }
    cout << "Child #" << getpid() << endl; // Child can keep going and fork once
  }

  wait(NULL);        // Don't let a parent ending first end the tree below
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
My process id = 6596
Child #6597
Child #6598
Child #6599
Child #6600
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `fork` in a set of nested `if`s

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
printf("Parent PID %d\n",getpid());
if(fork()==0)
{
    printf("child 1 \n");
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        printf("child 2 \n");
        if(fork()==0)
            printf("child 3 \n");
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Output

Parent PID 3857
child 1
child 2
child 3

For n processes,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void spawn(int n)
{
if(n)
{
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        if(n)
        {
            printf("Child %d \n",n);
            spawn(n-1);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
}
int main()
{   
printf("Parent PID %d\n",getpid());
int i=0;
spawn(5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how to make it, if I want to create N processes ?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do something similar. I want to spawn it until it reaches the maximum number of file processes that can be made and it unable to create any more processes. What shall I do in this case?

Answer (score -2):

```
int make_proc(int counter, int parent){
pid_t x=getpid();
std::cout << counter << " process "<< x << " : parent" << parent<< std::endl;


    if (counter==0) {
       return 1;
    }
    else {
        counter=counter-1;
        pid_t pid=fork();
       if (pid==0) return make_proc(counter, x);
       wait(NULL);

    }

}

--------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x=getpid();
    make_proc(10, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?